# ngOptions submitting object rather than option value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using a 'getPickupSchedules' directive to populate schedules based on the users zip code. After the user enters in a 5 digit zip code I do an `$http.get` to retrieve the schedules for their zip and build a select element. The values for each of these elements are their primary keys when I inspect the element but when the form gets submitted, the value for the `pickup_schedule` returns as an object with all of the other values rather than the `pickup_id` which leads me to errors on my server side. I know I could parse it to get the correct data but something tells me I shouldn't have to do that and either I'm probably missing or doing something wrong.

```
app.directive('getPickupSchedules', function($http){                  

    return {                                                                     
        restrict: 'A',                                                           
        replace: true,                                                           
        templateUrl: STATIC_URL + 'templates/directives/get_pickup_schedules.html',                     

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {                                                                                     

            scope.$watch('formData.zip', function() {                            
                zip = scope.formData.zip                                         

                if  (typeof zip !== 'undefined' && zip.length == 5)              
                {                                                                

                    $http.get('/get_schedules/' + zip)         
                        .then(function (results){                                
                            var pu = results.data                                
                            scope.pickupSchedules = results.data                 
                            console.log(scope.pickupSchedules);                  
                            scope.formData.pickupSchedules = scope.pickupSchedules[0]

                    });                                                          
                }                                                                
            });                                                                  

        }                                                                        
    }
```

get_pickup_schedules.html

```
<div>                                                                            
    <select                                                                      
            data-ng-options="(pickup.route + ' - ' + pickup.date) for pickup in pickupSchedules track by pickup.pickup_id"
            ng-model="formData.pickup_schedule">                                 
            <option value="">Select a pickup schedule</option>                   
    </select>                                                                    
</div>
```

Inspection on element:

```
<select data-ng-options="(pickup.route + ' - ' + pickup.date) for pickup in pickupSchedules track by pickup.pickup_id" ng-model="formData.pickup_schedule" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
 <option value="" class="">Select a pickup schedule</option>
 <option value="8297">Route 1 - 2014-06-18</option>
 <option value="8298">Route 2 - 2014-06-25</option>
 <option value="9543">Route 3 - 2014-07-02</option>
 <option value="9544">Route 4 - 2014-07-09</option>
 </select>
```

I have bound all of the form data into a `formData` variable. Here is the `console.log` of `formData.pickup_schedule` which is returning an object rather than the primary key as given in the option value.

```
pickup_schedule: Object
date: "2014-06-25"
driver: null
pickup_id: 8298
route: "Section 15"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a really hard time following what you are saying... but I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
<select data-ng-options="pickup.pickup_id as (pickup.route + ' - ' + pickup.date) for pickup in pickupSchedules" ng-model="formData.pickup_schedule">
```

Comment: Worked, thanks. Those options put the option values at 1,2,4,5, etc. The way I had it had the actual PK values. I don't quite understand why this works but the data submitted was the PK value.

Comment: when you use `as`, whatever is on the left of as is what gets assigned to the `ng-model`, whatever is on the right is the label.

Comment: Makes sense. Just seems odd to me that the option values in the HTML are shown differently then what they are once submitted. Thanks again. I'm new to Angular so maybe I'm just not thinking about it correctly.

Comment: You could add in ` track by pickup.pickup_id` which tells it how to keep track of which one is which, but it's not really necessary in this case, unless you really want the rendered html to match up